# Tabbar display issue in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios6

I made an application. Now I am testing the app on `iOS beta 6`. Everything is working fine but the little tabbar reflection layer appears above the Tabbar. I can not get why this appears.

I have attached a screenshot how it exactly looks like.

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You're better off asking about this at the Apple Developer Forums. iOS 6 is pre-release software, and is still under NDA which may put people off from answering you here.

Comment: ok..let me ask it at Apple Developer Forum.

Comment: I think this is by default by Apple...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I don't know the reason but it works.

I have used  `[self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:bgImgView]` instead of

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:bgImgView atIndex:1]
```

and it works with iOS 6. Now I don't get that reflection of tab bar.